# Передача двумерного массива структур в функцию

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++, структуры

Есть двумерный массив структур, я выделяю ему память и передаю по указателю в функцию:

```
result.capabilities = (Capabilities **)malloc(sizeof(Capabilities *)*6);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    result.capabilities[i] = (Capabilities *)malloc(sizeof(Capabilities)*8);
}
init_capabilities(&result.capabilities);
```

При вызове функции вылетает ошибка

> Unhandled exception at 0x003c10f9 in solution.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfdfdfdfd.

Вот фрагмент функции:

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities ***capabilities) {
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            capabilities[i][j]->room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
        }
    }
}
```

Я считал, что размерность массива `capabilities` — 6x8. Оказалось, что 1x6. То есть вместо указателя на двумерный массив структур функция интерпретирует аргумент как двумерный массив на указатель структуры.

Уже час ломаю голову из-за этого. Подскажите, как мне изменить тип аргумента функции или как правильно обращаться к элементам моего массива, чтобы всё стало на свои места?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
struct t
{
    int a;
};
void f(t** &q)
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            q[i][j].a=i+j;
}
int main()
{
    t **y=(t**)malloc(sizeof(t*)*5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        y[i]=(t*)malloc(sizeof(t)*8);
    }
    f(y);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            printf("%3d",y[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Передача по ссылке здесь очень уместна

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае происходит выделение памяти под *ступенчатый массив*: массив размером 6, который состоит из массивов размера 8, которые состоят из структур `Capabilities`.

Для работы с таким массивом следует изменить сигнатуру метода:

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities **capabilities)

// вызывать без получения указателя:
init_capabilities(result.capabilities);
```

и обращаться к элементам массива через

```
capabilities[i][j].room_capabilities = ...;
```

Если же необходимо иметь двумерный ступенчатый массив из *указателей* на `Capabilities`, тогда вызовы malloc'а стоит подправить соответствующим образом:

```
// массивы из T               -> массивы из T *
(T **)malloc(sizeof(T *) * n) -> (T ***)malloc(sizeof(T **) * n)
(T *)malloc(sizeof(T) * m)    -> (T **)malloc(sizeof(T *) * m)
```

Но т.к. в метках указан C++, то стоит использовать выделение массива через `new []`:

```
T **twoDimensional = new T *[n];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    twoDimensional[i] = new T[m];
}
```

Это удобнее и, что самое главное, для типа T вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

Решение - либо передача по ссылке, как предложил [[@BogolyubskiyAlexey](/users/557/bogolyubskiyalexey)](/users/557/bogolyubskiyalexey), либо исправить разыменование внутри функции. Вместо

```
capabilities[i][j]->room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
```

написать

```
(*capabilities)[i][j].room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
```